# Is limiting boxing thru these methods worth it?

Tags: c#, boxing

C# 3 btw...
So I am working on my AI blackboard. Part of that is  an associative map, of string names to a gerneric values (object), right now the value is stored as a boxed value type or a string cast to an object.

So something like this:

```
  public class ContextEntry
  {
    public string name;
    public object value;
  }

  public class BehaviorContext
  {
    public ContextEntry AddEntry<T>(string name, T value)
    {
      //checks to see if T is an allowed type, create a ContextEnetry
      //and adds it to map, returning a reference to the added entry
    }

    public bool GetValue<T>(string name, ref T val)
    {
      //look for entry, if found, do an as check with T, 
      //and then unbox the entry value into T
      //otherwise return false 
    }

    public bool GetValue(string name, ref object val)
    {
      //same as GetValue<T> but with object instead
    }

    public bool SetValue<T>(string name, T val)
    {
      //look for entry, if found, do an as check with T, 
      //and then box T into the entry value
      //otherwise return false 
    }

    public bool SetValue(string name, object val)
    {
      //same as SetValue<T> but instead checks val type is compatible with entry
    }

    protected Dictionary<string, ContextEntry> m_EntryMap = new Dictionary<string, ContextEntry>();
  }
```

For those adding entries, they can keep a copy of ContextEnty around and directly access the value from there.

So what I am seeing is the constant boxing and unbox is hurting me, when it comes to frame time, as this is used alot.

I was wondering if doing something like this for ContextEntry would be better.

```
public interface IContextEntry
  {
    string Name {get; set;} 
    bool SetObj(object o);
    void GetObj(ref object o);
  }  

  public class ContextEntry<T> : IContextEntry
  {
    public bool SetObj(object o) { //do a compatibility check then unbox into value }
    public void GetObj(ref object o) { //box value into o }
    public T value;
  }
```

Now i would keep a seperate dictionary of ContextEntry[T] per allowable type, and only search in right one if some one used GetValue[T] or  SetValue[T]. If someone uses GetValue or SetValue, i would also keep a dictionary of IContextEntry with all entries. A user would use the templated versions of the functions often but also the non templated version often as well. When using a the non-templated versions, they would induce a virtual function call as well a boxing/unboxing.

Im wondering if its worth it. Any opinions?

Comment: I wonder...if boxing/unboxing is **really** hurting performance (but you should **measure**) then you may keep different **typed dictionaries** (at least for common value types) **plus one list of objects**. Then provide **typed overloaded methods** (for both get/set) plus one generic one. I can't see how IContextEntry will help you. What, keeping that approach, you may do is to **make ContextEntry a typed struct/class** used with overloaded methods (so you won't need to keep separated lists). From a typed struct you can always get a boxed value (for compatibility with untyped gets).

Comment: If (un)boxing is hurting your performance then you have a very optimized code already i.e. (un)boxing is quite fast and there is a high probability that it is a non-issue performance-wise.

Comment: Why are you using `Object` anyway?  If you think that's where your performance problems lie, use a generic and not `Object`...

Comment: I don't see any `struct` in your sample... Not sure what "boxing"/"unboxing" you are talking about. Please show sample code that matches your definition of "boxing".

Comment: He doesn't show any use of methods that take Object parameters--one can be assured any use of those methods with value types (structs) would result in boxing.